# Sort a vector of custom objects

Tags: java, sorting, vector

How can I sort a vector of my custom object and choose which property to sort by?

I did see this question & answer but I'm not too sure what its sorting it based on. Code example would be prefered to "methodology".

[Sort a Vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568059/sort-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

```
public class ItemLocation {
    String icon;
    String title;
    String message;
    String subtext;
    String deviceId;
    double latCoords;
    double lngCoords;
    int expiary;
    int id;
    double proximity;
    String locSeen;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `java.util.Vector` unless you have a really good reason. That class dates Java1.1 and is pretty much replaced by `java.util.Arraylist`

Comment: using a nested if statements like that is not a very good OO solution. Also you can't just invoke "compareTo" on the primitive data types so the code becomes more complex.

Comment: Vector is synchronized and methods accessing its content are thread safe. ArrayList isn't. Vector doubles its array when more space is needed, ArrayList increases the size by 50%. There are other differences which one should consider when choosing between Vector and ArrayList. See [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077425/java-se/vector-or-arraylist-which-is-better.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is a example that will allow you to sort by a specified field of ItemLocation:

```
public void sort(final String field, List<ItemLocation> itemLocationList) {
    Collections.sort(itemLocationList, new Comparator<ItemLocation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
            if(field.equals("icon")) {
                return o1.icon.compareTo(o2.icon);
            } if(field.equals("title")) {
                return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
            } else if(field.equals("message")) {
                return o1.message.compareTo(o2.message);
            } 
            .
            . fill in the rest of the fields...
            .
            else if(field.equals("locSeen")) {
                return o1.locSeen.compareTo(o2.locSeen);
            } 
        }           
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kurt :) This way I can sort easily by any of the fields in the vector of my custom object.

Comment: Fantastic Kurt! I got this to work in a matter of minutes after a slight adjustment to support the primitive double type. 
return (o1.proximity < o2.proximity)?-1:(o1.proximity > o2.proximity)?1:0;

Answer (score 5):

See the JavaDocs for `java.util.Comparable` and `java.util.Comparator`.

A class that implements `Comparable` can be compared against other instances of that class.  This is useful to implement a natural search order.  To allow ordering other than the class's natural order you would need to implement a `Comparator`.  A `Comparator` is a separate object that is capable of comparing two other objects using whatever criteria it wants.

In your case you'd probably want to implement a `Comparator` for each of the different properties that you want to order by, or one that can be configured.

`Comparable` and `Comparator` both use the same idea to determine ordering: A method returns less than 0, 0, or greater than 0 to inform the caller which of the 2 objects is ordered first.  In the case of `Comparable` the first object is `this`.

Comment: "Code example would be preferred to methodology" - in other words, he would like you to do it for him. Pfft..

Comment: Just saying this is a new concept and more concepts do not help. Concrete code to study is a much more effective learning tool.

Answer (score 5):

This one works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * ComparableDemo
 * @author Michael
 * @since 2/24/11
 */
public class ComparableDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<ItemLocation> itemLocations = new ArrayList<ItemLocation>();
        for (String arg : args)
        {
            itemLocations.add(new ItemLocation(arg));
        }

        System.out.println("before sort: " + itemLocations);
        Comparator<ItemLocation> comparator = new ItemLocationComparator();
        Collections.sort(itemLocations, comparator);
        System.out.println("after  sort: " + itemLocations);
    }
}

class ItemLocation
{
    String icon;
    String title;
    String message;
    String subtext;
    String deviceId;
    double latCoords;
    double lngCoords;
    int expiary;
    int id;
    double proximity;
    String locSeen;

    ItemLocation(String message)
    {
        this("", "", message, "", "", 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, "");
    }

    ItemLocation(String icon, String title, String message, String subtext, String deviceId, double latCoords, double lngCoords, int expiary, int id, double proximity, String locSeen)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.subtext = subtext;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.latCoords = latCoords;
        this.lngCoords = lngCoords;
        this.expiary = expiary;
        this.id = id;
        this.proximity = proximity;
        this.locSeen = locSeen;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ItemLocation");
        sb.append("{message='").append(message).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}



class ItemLocationComparator implements Comparator<ItemLocation>
{
    public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2)
    {
        return o1.message.compareTo(o2.message);
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
C:\JDKs\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain ComparableDemo zeb meme apple
before sort: [ItemLocation{message='zeb'}, ItemLocation{message='meme'}, ItemLocation{message='apple'}]
after  sort: [ItemLocation{message='apple'}, ItemLocation{message='meme'}, ItemLocation{message='zeb'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we have a class with an int and a string. I can define how one object of that class may  be compared against other.

I could choose any criteria. For instance, I may decide to sort based on the int. If I happen to have two int's with the same value, I may decide the string as an additional criteria, something like this:

```
 // this class *knows* how  to  "compare" against him self
class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> { 
    String aString;
    int aInt;
     ...
    public int compareTo(CustomObject two ) {
        int diff = this.aInt - two.aInt;//<-- compare ints
        if( diff != 0 ) { // they have different int
            return diff;
        }    
        return this.aString.compareTo( two.aString );//<-- compare strings... 
   }
   ...
}
```

Here's a complete running demo ...

```
import java.util.*;
class SortDemo { 
    public static void main( String ... args ) { 
        // create a bunch and sort them 
        List<CustomObject> list = Arrays.asList(
            new CustomObject(3, "Blah"),
            new CustomObject(30, "Bar"),
            new CustomObject(1, "Zzz"),
            new CustomObject(1, "Aaa")
        );
        System.out.println( "before: "+ list );
        Collections.sort( list );
        System.out.println( "after : "+ list );
    }
}
 // this class *knows* how  to  "compare" against him self
class CustomObject implements Comparable<CustomObject> { 
    String aString;
    int aInt;
    CustomObject( int i, String s ) { 
        aInt = i;
        aString = s;
    }
    // comparable interface lets you
    // specify "HOW" to compare two 
    // custom objects
    public int compareTo(CustomObject two ) {
        // I migth compare them using the int first 
        // and if they're the same, use the string... 
        int diff = this.aInt - two.aInt;
        if( diff != 0 ) { // they have different int
            return diff;
        }

        // else let the strings compare them selves
        return this.aString.compareTo( two.aString );
   }
   public String toString(){
       return "CustomObject[aInt="+aInt+", aString="+aString+"]";
   }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
before: [CustomObject[aInt=3, aString=Blah], CustomObject[aInt=30, aString=Bar], CustomObject[aInt=1, aString=Zzz], CustomObject[aInt=1, aString=Aaa]]
after : [CustomObject[aInt=1, aString=Aaa], CustomObject[aInt=1, aString=Zzz], CustomObject[aInt=3, aString=Blah], CustomObject[aInt=30, aString=Bar]]
```

I hope that's clear enough

You can also pass a custom comparator. Let me know if you need a sample of that.