# Sorting a List of Objects Based on 1 of its Fields

Tags: java, sorting

Hello stackoverflow community!
I am new to these forums and also fairly new to java and android programming--which happen to be the objects of my question--so sorry in advance for any blunders!

My issue is sorting. I am looking for a method to sort objects based on a field that I choose (not sorting based on the first field, then the next, etc. exemplified by comparator chaining). I believe I've found the solution to my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5113108/1549672

but I am having trouble actually getting this to work. I have a suspicion that I'm probably missing something due to my lack of java experience, so any help is welcome!

Here is what I am trying:

As my class-

```
public class ItemLocation {
String title;
int id;
}
```

As my function-

```
public void sort(final String field, List<ItemLocation> itemLocationList) {
    Collections.sort(itemLocationList, new Comparator<ItemLocation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
            if(field.equals("title")) {
                return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
            } else if(field.equals("id")) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.id).compareTo(o2.id);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

using these, could someone possibly give an example of using this method? I attempted to fill an ArrayList and sort it, but to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not return `0` from the [`Comparator.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) method if they are not equal. It's "okey" by the contract, but not exactly encouraged, from the API documentation:

> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x,
>   y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that
>   violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The
>   recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that
>   are inconsistent with equals."

---

In my opinion you should return a specific [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for each field instead:

```
Comparator<ItemLocation> titleComparator = new Comparator<ItemLocation>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
        return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
    }
}

Comparator<ItemLocation> idComparator = new Comparator<ItemLocation>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.id).compareTo(o2.id);
    }
}

public void sort(final String field, List<ItemLocation> itemLocationList) {

    final Comparator<ItemLocation> comparator;

    if(field.equals("title")) {
        comparator = titleComparator;
    } else if (field.equals("id")) {
        comparator = idComparator;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Comparator not found for " + field);
    }

    Collections.sort(itemLocationList, comparator);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir! the reason I included the return 0 is because the eclipse was telling me that the method had to return an integer and I wasn't sure what else to put! And this is a much simpler implementation to understand coming from a C++ background! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the calling code that is not working?  I can't see anything clearly wrong with the code you've provided.

Firstly, you might try is putting an extra else case like so:

```
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised field name");
}
```

At the moment, if you had a typo in your calling code, the comparator would always return 0, which would leave the list unsorted.

A more robust way of passing the field would be to declare an enum:

```
enum ItemLocationField {
    TITLE,
    ID
}
```

Then your conditions would become:

```
if (field == ItemLocationField.TITLE)
```

and so on.  That would reduce the chances of making a typo (the compiler will tell you if you do).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong except `returning 0` and comparing parameter with `equals` . you can improve it by `throwing RuntimeException` rather than `returning 0` and use `equalsIgnoreCase` rather than `equals` method , better to ignore the case of parameter.

```
public static void sort(final String field, List<ItemLocation> itemLocationList) {
    Collections.sort(itemLocationList, new Comparator<ItemLocation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ItemLocation o1, ItemLocation o2) {
            if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                return o1.title.compareTo(o2.title);
            } else if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.id).compareTo(o2.id);
            }else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Parameter .");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think that was mostly due to my lack of experience with java...Eclipse just told me that the implementation had to return an integer!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want to Sort object on the **basis of only one attribute**, then go for `java.lang.Comparable` Interface along with `Collections.sort(List<T> list)`

**2.** If you want to Sort the object on the basis of **more than one attributes**, then go for
       `java.util.Comparator` Interface along with `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

Comment: thanks! i was mostly looking for a way to sort based on ONE attribute of objects containing MULTIPLE attributes!

Comment: Ya.. thats what my 1st point suggest..... sorting on the basis of one attribute. 2nd point was an add-on for extra knowledge