# how to sort the Vector containing objects using Blackberry API

Tags: sorting, blackberry, java-me, vector

I want to sort a vector which contains Object of following fields

```
public class CategoryListing   {

     String company_id;
     String company_name;
     double distance;

     //setters and getters here 
}
```

I populated the vector from webservice, now I want to sort that vector by distance, means I want to show nearest one. How can I sort the vector which contains  objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113006/sort-a-vector-of-custom-objects Or if you use a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: It is not the same Question. Black Berry only supports Java 1.3 Limited functionality. There is no `Collections` class. I think question needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Comparator](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/com/google/zxing/common/Comparator.html).

Define a comparator which will sort on distance like below

```
public class DistanceComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return Double.valueOf(((CategoryListing) o1).distance)
                .compareTo(((CategoryListing) o2).distance);// use getters
    }
}
```

Sort vector using `below sort method`. Note As [Arrays](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator%29) are present from 1.2 It is also present for blackberry.

public static void sort(Vector vector,Comparator comparator) {

```
    Object[] array = new Object[vector.size()];   
    vector.copyInto(array);   

    Arrays.sort(array,comparator);

    int i = 0;
    Enumeration enumumeration = vector.elements();
    while (enumumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        enumumeration.nextElement();
        vector.insertElementAt(array[i++], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Collections is not availbale in blackberry sdk

Comment: Correction to previous post - Generics aren't supported in BlackBerry as well as annotations. It's Supports limited 1.3 only

Comment: i am not able to find collection class so i can not implement it

Comment: Amit its not my negative you are helping me how i can provide negative,

Comment: @Ali Above code will work for you. Try it let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: ListIterator is not available in blackberry

Comment: Errr. Life would have been difficult to work on BB. Check the updated solution. I have checked it has `Enumeration` so you can use that.

Comment: or use my solution using SimpleSortingVector  :-) .There is no need to convert vector to array, then sort it and then set the vector again. too much code and calculations which are not required.

Comment: -1 in BB 7 API, there is no `java.util.Comparator`, see **[Blackberry API javadocs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/util/package-frame.html)**

Comment: @gnat if you would have done `Frames` you would have found it here is the [link](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/com/google/zxing/common/Comparator.html) from your link only

Comment: @AmitD I see, you're right. Reverted my vote from down to up :)

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers are going to work for you on Blackberry as it doesn't support Generics. Blackberry uses older version of Java. Try the following code. It uses [SimpleSortingVector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/SimpleSortingVector.html)

```
    SimpleSortingVector sortVector = new SimpleSortingVector();
    sortVector.setSortComparator(new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            CategoryListing o1C = (CategoryListing)o1;
            CategoryListing o2C = (CategoryListing)o2;
            return Double.toString((o1C.distance)).compareTo(Double.toString(o2C.distance));
        }
    });
            //when you add elements to this vector, it is automatically sorted by distance
    sortVector.addElement(new CategoryListing());
```